# Apple Mach- O Linker Error Can't open file, errno= 13

Tags: xcode, azure, unity-game-engine

When I build my Unity porject in Xcode I get that error and build fails.  This is a demo from Azure spatial anchors.  I also get " Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

In general,  it's missing libraries linker..etc
Some unity plugin use native libraries. When you build from Unity, they will try to edit your xcode project via some script like "BuildPostProcessor.cs" for example.

In different version of unity, it exports different name of xcode files.
If you found any warning message or error during your Unity build log, you should look further.

below is one of solution for Build Post Processor related scripts.

```
#if !UNITY_2019_3_OR_NEWER
        string tn = "Unity-iPhone";
#else
        string tn = "UnityFramework";
#endif
```

Comment: Yes it is showing errors.  One says Script attached to 'Sphere' in scene "is missing or no valid script is attached.  UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&).  An additional one for '_PlaneThatCallsIntoPlugin'.   In Xcode I get :  ld: can't open file, errno=13 file '/Users/davidmiller/Desktop/azure sample test/azure test 2 xcode/Libraries/libil2cpp.a' for architecture arm64.  Then. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I am new to Unity/ Azure/ Xcode/ etc.  lol

Comment: @skynard do you have screenshots of your xcode project folder?
But it seems that you have to fix the error on Unity side first.
You can still manually select the path of your source library for the xcode file, it should still be somewhere your xcode folders.

Comment: Getting these errors on the build in Unity:  Script attached to 'Sphere' in scene '' is missing or no valid script is attached.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) and Script attached to '_PlaneThatCallsIntoPlugin' in scene '' is missing or no valid script is attached.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I was trying to run ASA with a version of Unity that was not compatible.  Once that was fixed  I was able to export to the phone.  I don't think I set up the camera correctly but the app runs.  lol